Problemas con mi codigo de React, no puedo hacer un intercambiar componentes con un click
Estoy comenzando con React. Estoy haciendo una lista de tareas donde puedo agregar,buscar y remover tareas, además esta lista también me debe permitir marcar y desmarcar como completado una tarea en especifico que ya realice de las lista de tareas. Estoy usando dos iconos de la librería de iconos de React, uno para cuando la tarea este incompleta y otro para cuando la tarea ya este completada, el problema esta en que cuando quiero marcar la tarea como completada o incompleta no logro hacer que se muestre un icono y desaparezca el otro.
He usado los estados, clases y operadores ternarios para hacer que esto funcione pero los resultados que he obtenido son por ejemplo, que al marcar o desmarcar una tarea se vea afectado todas las demás tareas de la lista o que pueda hacer desaparecer un icono la primera vez, pero al marcar o desmarcar de nuevo la tarea ambos iconos se desaparezcan, me gastaría obtener algún consejo o soporte de la comunidad, gracias, aquí adjunto el código usado:
mi archivo principal App
    import './App.css';
    import Task from './components/Task/Task';
    import AddTask from './components/AddTask/AddTask';
    import Search from './components/Search/Search';
    import React , { useState } from 'react';
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

    function App() {
     const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState({});
     const [arrTask, setArrTask] = useState([]);
     const [searchTask, setSearchTask] = useState("");

   return (
   <>
    <div className='main_container'>

      <div className='card_new_task'>
        <h1>Lista de Tareas</h1>
        <h2>5 Tareas completadas de 15</h2>
        <div className='addTask'>
          <AddTask 
          newTask={newTask}
          setNewTask={setNewTask}
          arrTask={arrTask}
          setArrTask={setArrTask}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div className='task'>
        <Search searchTask={searchTask} setSearchTask={setSearchTask} arrTask={arrTask} setArrTask={setArrTask}/>
        {arrTask.map((task) => {
          return <Task key={uuidv4()} task={task.title} id={task.id} arrTask={arrTask} setArrTask={setArrTask}  setNewTask={setNewTask}/>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
    
</>
     );
    }

   export default App;

Mi archivo AddTask que me permite añadir tareas
    import React from 'react';
    import "./AddTask.css";
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

    const AddTask = ({newTask,setNewTask,arrTask,setArrTask}) => {
    return<>
    <input typeof="text" placeholder="Escribe una tarea por hacer ..." className="task_value" onChange={(e) => {
        
        setNewTask({
            title:e.target.value,
            id:uuidv4(),
            complete:true
        });
    }}/>
    <button onClick={() => {
            setArrTask([...arrTask, newTask]);
    }}>Agregar</button>
     </>
    }

    export default AddTask;

Y mi archivo AddTask que es donde tengo el problema, en el div con la clase complete e incomplete
    import "./Task.css";
    import React from 'react';
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { FaCheckCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
    import { MdCancel } from "react-icons/md";
    import { FaMinusCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

    const Task = ({task,id,arrTask,setArrTask}) => {
    return <>
    <div className="new_task">
        <MdCancel className="cancel"  onClick={() =>{
            setArrTask(arrTask.filter((element) => element.id !== id))
        }}    
        />
        <div className="complete">
           
            <FaCheckCircle className="inactive" onClick={(e) => {
                
            }}/>
        </div>

        <div className="incomplete">
            <FaMinusCircle className={arrTask.map(element => element.id === id ? (element.complete === false ? "active": "inactive"):console.log("Hola"))}  onClick={(e) =>{
                
            }}/>
        </div>
        <p>{task}</p>
    </div>
    </>
    }

    export default Task;

